# Ways to manage secrets in Hashicorp Vault

Tags: security, configuration, devops, hashicorp-vault

guys!
I've just started to use Vault for our applications, and I've noticed few areas for improvement.
So I want to gather more information how it could be done.
I used kv secret engine and have created next path structure:

```
/{env}/services/{service}
```

**env** could be sand/stage/prod1/prod2...
**services** could be app1/app2/app3...
The first problem is - **secrets duplications**. 
For example:
**app1** and **app2** need to communicate between each other and they have keys/secrets to do that. So I need to go and add keys/secrets in two places at least: **/{env}/services/app1** and **/{env}/services/app2**
I came up with solution as master-slave secrets. For example:

1. Create **/{env}/common** secret and gather all duplications in this place.
2. Create **/{env}/nested** secret and set there secrets as common secret key and paths to services: **APP1_USERNAME=/{env}/services/app1,/{env}/services/app2**
3. Create l-function to fetch **/{env}/common** secrets by keys from **/{env}/nested** and write them to paths defined in **/{env}/nested** secret values
4. Trigger function once an hour/two/three...

The second problem is - how to automate secrets adding, or how to notify developers at least.
For example: Developer finished to develop new feature that should use new configuration parameter, and forgot to push it into vault.
Pull request was successfully reviewed and merged, new code deployed and doesn't started due to lack of parameters.
I have some thoughts to use gitHub actions for code scanning and checking secrets in vault.

Is there any practices to handle such situations?